# Error when trying to access to a function in my service

Tags: angular, socket.io

I'm trying to implement a web app in angular with some socket.io. I use `ngx-socket-io`.

I have a service like that :

```js
import { Socket } from 'ngx-socket-io';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';


@Injectable()
export class IoRequestService {
  constructor(private socket: Socket) { }
  
  sendMessage(msg: string) {
    this.socket.emit("message", msg);
  }

  getMessage() {
        return this.socket
            .fromEvent("message")
            .pipe(map((data:any) => data.msg));
   }
}
```

and then I try to use it in a component like that

```js
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Transaction } from '../models/Transaction.model'
import { IoRequestService } from '../services/ioRequest.service'

@Component({
  selector: 'app-transactions',
  templateUrl: './transactions.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./transactions.component.scss']
})
export class TransactionsComponent implements OnInit {
  transactions: Transaction[] = [];
  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }

  send() {
    IoRequestService.sendMessage("txt");
  }

}
```

But I have a error :

```
Property 'sendMessage' does not exist on type 'typeof IoRequestService'.
```

Do you have any idea why does this happens?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since `IoRequestService` is annotated with `@Injectable()` you need to [inject its instance](https://angular.io/guide/dependency-injection) in your component:

```
constructor(private service: IoRequestService) {
}

send() {
  this.service.sendMessage("txt");
}
```

Also add `IoRequestService` in your `AppModule`:

```
@NgModule({
  ...
  providers: [
    IoRequestService
  ]
  ...
})
export class AppModule {
}
```

Comment: ok, thanks. I don't really understand what Injectable are btw, I just paste the code of the doc...

Answer (score 0):

You need to inject the service in the component before accessing it

```
constructor(private _reService: IoRequestService) { }
```

and call the method as,

```
  send() {
    _reService.sendMessage("txt");
  }
```